# How do I perfom a partial update for an existing Solr document using Solr 5.2.1 and PHP 5.6.27?

Tags: php, curl, solr

First I tried the following, based on https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/apache-solr-php/9781782164920/ch02s04.html :

```
$update = $solrClient->createUpdate();
$doc = $update->createDocument();
$doc->setKey('id', "systemx en 1 194502");
$doc->setField('name', 'george');
$doc->setFieldModifier('sku', 'set');
$update->addDocument($doc)->addCommit();
$result = $solrClient->update($update);
var_dump($result);
```

Apparently, my version of the solr client (2.4.0) does not support such functionality.  I go the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method SolrClient::createUpdate() in /opt/labs/developers/yfischer/gend7/tools/testyf.php on line 23
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /opt/labs/developers/yfischer/gend7/tools/testyf.php:0
```

Then, I tried using  curl directly.

```
$post = json_encode(array(array(
    'id' => 'systemx en 1 194502',
    'name' => array('set' => 'george')
)));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://myserver:8983/solr/dev/update?commit=true');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_exec ($ch); curl_close ($ch);
```

I got the following output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":132}}
```

Nevertheless, when I try querying the document using http://myserver:8983/solr/dev/select?q=*%3A*&fq=id%3A%22systemx+en+1+194502%22&wt=json&indent=true , the name field remains unchanged.

Comment: `Contenttype` should probably be `Content-Type` in your curl entry, at least. What does the Solr log say? Also, the example in the book uses Solarium - which is a pure PHP library for talking to Solr, so you can just update that library without changing your PHP installation.

Comment: Thanx,  MatsLindh, but unfortunately this did not help.
Editited the content-type header as you suggested, and I get a response in json: {"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":238}}
Still, the record is not updated.
Also, from https://pecl.php.net/package/solr , it seems the latest stable version of the solr client is 2.4.0, which is the version that I am using.

Comment: But the book you're referencing is not using the PECL Solr extension. It's using [the Solarium PHP Library](https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium). If you're going to follow the examples, you'll have to use the same library that the examples are written for.

Comment: Thanx,  MatsLindh.  Your comment helped.  If you want to put it as an answer, I can award you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book you're referencing is not using the PECL Solr extension. It's using the Solarium PHP Library. If you're going to follow the examples, you'll have to use the same library that the examples are written for.

The Solarium library [does have built-in support for updates](https://solarium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/queries/update-query/building-an-update-query/building-an-update-query/), while the binary Solr extension currently doesn't have specific update support (but you can go through the [general `request` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/solrclient.request.php) which allows submitting your own XML with an update request).